# What are other way to get current location apart from IP address?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently using Google's getCurrentPosition method to get current location of the user. But The problem is, Google is picking the current location through IP and if user's ISP is from some other location, it is showing me location from there. So is there any other way to get the exact location of the user apart from IP based.

Comment: That's what I am using!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

geolocation(it's not a Google-API, it's a browser-feature) can only use available data.

When the environment of the user doesn't provide better data than  an IP-address, you only have the option  to let the user choose his location on it's own (e.g. by clicking on a map)

Comment: Well!! I have given option to user to manually enter the location. But wanted to know if there is another way to correct the location if user hit the button.

Comment: As I said, it depends on the users environment how exact the result will be. geolocation isn't always IP-based...when the environment supports other techniques(e.g.  GPS/wireless connection) you'll get better results via geolocation(as you know it on mobile devices). You on your own can't do anything.